# curlopt_cookie doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, curl

This is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www1.macys.com/index.ognc');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"shippingCountry=US; currency=USD");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "C:/cookie-techenclave.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "C:/cookie-techenclave.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     // Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 8);             // Limit redirections to four
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);     // Return in string

$pageString = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch) ;
```

The 2 cookies I am attempting to set are not getting set. I tested this with netcat.
This is the output captured by netcat.

```
D:\php\L.c.MSQL.E.T.DVD\EF\SQL> "D:\My Downloads\apps\nc111nt\nc.exe" -l -p 80
GET /beauty/index_template.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.64
Host: localhost
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-x
bitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

As can be seen there is no cookie header in there. What am I doing wrong? What else can i try?
I tried capturing and setting all the headers , but again the cookies I am attempting to set didn't have any effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use CURLOPT_COOKIE if you want curl auto update cookie's value base on server response.
because request cookie will hardcoded to the value of CURLOPT_COOKIE. CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR will be ignored on this case.

And are you sure the provided network sniff is from the above PHP code? I don't see the USER_AGENT get set on the code but it's available on your sniff.

Comment: but then how do I set a cookie, without curlopt_cookie. And yes the user-agent is the browsers. I removed the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to test things.

Comment: CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE & CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR is your friend.
To test some default cookie value, you should google for curl cookie file format.

Comment: IT worked! I set the 2 cookies manually in the cookie file. Then set curlopt_Cookiefile and curlopt_cookiejar and it finally worked. Thanks

Comment: can you please help me or update yu question with a proper answer?