# SharePoint web service persistent authentication using PHP

Tags: php, authentication, sharepoint, curl, cookies

I want to build a php application that uses a restful SharePoint web service (https with simple http authentication).

I did a request with CURL and all works but it took a very long time (3sec). After a little debugging i found out that at each request the authentication took most of that time because it does some redirects and so on.

This does not happen in the browser, after the first request the authentication is persistent.

What i tried to do is mimic this with 2 different calls: 1 to get the WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated Cookie and another one to actually get the web service. I remember the cookie in a session variable and i use it for all the subsequent calls to the web service.

The problem is that the second request (that uses the cookie) does not authenticate (http 401).

Here is the first request that successfully gets the cookie:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://server/default.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

This is the second request that tries to use the cookie to achieve persistent authentication:

```
 $ch = curl_init('https://server/somewebservice/');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, implode(';', $session_key));
```

This gives 401.

Is it something i am missing?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633857/curlopt-cookie-doesnt-seem-to-be-working

Comment: No change. I still get 401.